# get number of lines of code of a function in python

Tags: python, line-numbers

I have a function in python.
Is there a way to get the number of lines of code that the function has in the original source file?

e.g.

```
# main.py

import f1 from mylib

print(loc(f1)) # 3

# mylib

def f1():
  pass
  return
```

Comment: Use correct import syntax for python.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this programmatically or wih external tools?

Comment: Briefly: `inspect.getsource(f1).count('\n')+1` or `len(inspect.getsourcelines(f1)[0])` (probably better).

Comment: programmatically

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 's way works for me! Thank you very much!!!